# Use Nginx to prevent downstream timeout by sending blank lines

Tags: django, nginx, timeout, cdn

We have a setup where a CDN is calling Nginx which is calling a uwsgi server. Some of the requests take a lot of time for Django to handle, so we are relying on the CDN for caching. However, the CDN has a hard timeout of 30 seconds, which is unfortunately not configurable.

If we were able to send a blank line every few seconds before the request is received from the uwsgi server, it would mean that the CDN would not timeout. Is there a way to send a blank line every few seconds with Nginx until the response is received?

Answer (score 0):

I see a few possibilities:

1. Update your Django app to work this way-- have /it/ start dribbling a response immediately.
2. Rework your design to avoid user's periodically having requests that take more than 30 seconds to respond. Use a frequent cron job to prime the cache on your backend server, so when the CDN asks for assets, they are already ready. Web servers can be configured to check for a static ".gz" versions of URLs, which might be a good fit here.
3. Configure Nginx to cache the requests. The first time the CDN requests the slow URL, it may timeout, but Nginx ought to eventually cache the result anyway. The next time the CDN asks, Nginx should have the cached response ready.